# Group By and Summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a quick question, I did a group by and summarize function for the following data by doing this. However, How do I summarize the length of the variable (Trump, Obama, McConnell) individually.

```
dta.subset.tabluea = dta.subset %>%
  group_by(variable,catvalue2) %>%
  summarize(value = length(catvalue))
```

the output i got was

```
 variable     catvalue2 value
1                Trump Slightly Warm   216
2                Trump     Very Cold   778
3                Trump     Very Warm   311
4                Trump          <NA>   176
5                Obama Slightly Warm   251
6                Obama     Very Cold   427
7                Obama     Very Warm   676
8                Obama          <NA>   224
9            McConnell Slightly Warm   248
10           McConnell     Very Cold   731
11           McConnell     Very Warm    60
12           McConnell          <NA>   444
```

However, How do I summarize the length of the variable (Trump, Obama, McConnell) in another column. I need this info so I can make percentages.

If i do the following, I would get the same answers as the first column.

```
summarize(value = length(catvalue), varvalue = length(vatvalue))
```

Comment: Use `n()` instead of `length`  If you need a new column, instead of `summarise`, use `mutate`

Comment: I am sorry, i am a pleb. 

Would the right code be

`code

dta.subset.tabluea = dta.subset %>%
  group_by(variable,catvalue2) %>%
  summarize(value2 = length(value) %>%
              mutate(varcount,n(variable)))
`

Comment: I meant `dta.subset %>% group_by(variable,catvalue2)  %>% summarise(value2 = n()) %>% group_by(catvalue2) %>% mutate(varvalue = n())`